# Can't figure out how to change this yaml file on google cloud platform

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Maybe i just don't get how to maneuver on GCP, but this tutorial:

'https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/tutorials/bookshelf-on-kubernetes-engine'

Doesn't explain how I change the ".yaml" file.. there's no directory I can just open the file and change it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you call the commands locally or in the 'web console'?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the .yaml file locally on your computer and then run

```
kubectl apply -f [path to the yaml file]
```

You can also edit the yaml on kubernetes dashboard. Go to GCP console, select the Kubernetes section, select workloads, go the specific workload and click 'edit'. It will take you to the .yaml file and then you can change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cloud shell code editor:

[image]